# Do we have multi delete java api in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to delete multiple keys in from couchbase in one call. Do we have something like bulkGet for delete in couchbase?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21481552/1793718

Comment: See http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.0/documents-bulk.html.

This demonstrates a generic way to do batching operations

Comment: Thank you . I was looking for bulkDelete operation like bulkget in couchbaseclient api. It has delete which deletes single key . It seems i have to manage myself a thread pool and queue to implement bulkdelete .

Answer (score 1):

Bulk delete is [definitely there](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/couchbase.html#multi-key-data-methods), but it requires you to pass KEYs to be deleted as argument list. So it might not be possible to delete all the required records in just one call. Essentially, what you would be doing is ([refer this link for an example](http://blog.couchbase.com/mass-deleting-documents-by-compound-key-prefix-using-node-js)):

- Query the data from the Couchbase
- Iterate over resultset
- and fire delete for each key of your interest.

However, I believe: Delete on server should be delete on server, rather than requiring three steps as above.

In this regards, I think old fashioned RDBMS were better all you need to do is fire SQL query like 'DELETE * from database where something like "match%"'.

Fortunately, there is something similar to SQL is available in CouchBase called N1QL (pronounced nickle). I am not aware about JavaScript (and other language syntax) but this is how I did it in python.

## Query to be used: DELETE from  b where META(b).id LIKE "%"

```
layer_name_prefix = cb_layer_key + "|" + "%"
query = ""
try:
    query = N1QLQuery('DELETE from `test-feature` b where META(b).id LIKE $1', layer_name_prefix)
    cb.n1ql_query(query).execute()
except CouchbaseError, e:
    logger.exception(e)
```

To achieve the same thing: alternate query could be as below if you are storing 'type' and/or other meta data like 'parent_id'.

## DELETE from  where type='Feature' and parent_id=8;

But I prefer to use first version of the query as it operates on key, and I believe Couchbase must have some internal indexes to operate/query faster on key (and other metadata).